# which linux to use for embedded-linux-qt 4 development?

Tags: linux, embedded, qt4

I want to start development using qt-embedded on my embedded device project. Can you tell me which linux should I use on my computer for development. Well, It should have VMWARE-tools support ( Fedora Core 11 does not have it ).

Thanks, Sunny.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got a whole dedicated website for this issue ([crosscompile.org](http://www.crosscompile.org)) ;-)

Anyway, we use ubuntu and at http://www.crosscompile.org/static/pages/crosstool.html you can see the toolchain building process

Hope it helps you.